# How to order a table by column index in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm not an expert of HTML, Javascript and CSS, I have the following situation:

```
 <div class="table">

      <table class="display-table">
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th class="col-table">Index</th>
                <th class="col-table">feature</th>


                <th class="col-table">other columns ...</th>  

            </tr>
        </thead>

        other code

      </table>
    </div>
```

There's a way to order the table according to the Index column (that contains integer numbers)? And is it possible to do it from HTML or should I write some other code in js? Right now, each time I'm adding a new record in the table, it is putted at the end of the table, even if it present an index lower than the last one.
Thank you!

Comment: "it is put at the end of the table", who is doing this? Do you have some framework, creating templates or html for you? If so, you should mention this in your question.

Comment: You should post the code which adds records.

Comment: One solution would be to maintain your data in an array/array of objects, and then use that to create/update the table.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way of sorting a table with HTML5 or CSS alone.

You will have to write some JS Code or get one of the many libraries having this functionality.

An example is jQuery (which also provide many additional functionality without diving into JS too deeply - be aware, that does not mean your shouldn't do so!). There are many tutorials around, like [this one](https://www.educba.com/bootstrap-sort-table/)

If you want to sort a table with vanilla code, take a look here:

[w3Schools - How TO - Sort a Table](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp)

Basically you need a callback, which is triggered on new row, and on data loaded.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please see [answer].

Comment: the answer is "it can't be done", so it is an answer.